# Android Compose - Radiogroup/RadioButton initial state vs changes

Tags: android, radio-button, android-jetpack-compose, radio-group

I've been playing around with compose recently and I'm facing a situation I'm not sure how to properly solve.

I have a radio group to display, so naturally, I created a function that looks like this:

```
@Composable
private fun RadioGroup(
    options: List<String>?,
    selectedOption: String?,
    onOptionSelected: (String) -> Unit
) =
    options?.forEach { item ->
        Row(
            Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            RadioButton(
                selected = (item == selectedOption),
                onClick = { onOptionSelected(item) },
            )

            ClickableText(
                text = AnnotatedString(item),
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
                style = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold),
                onClick = {
                    onOptionSelected(item)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

I'm calling this function for the initial state (providing the list of buttons and a selected button) by observing a livedata:

```
val state = viewModel.viewState.observeAsState().value

RadioGroup(
        state?.options,
        state?.selected,
        { option -> viewModel.onOptionSelected(option) }
    )
```

The livedata viewState providing the following data:

```
class ViewState(val options: List<String>, val selected: String)
```

But now, everytime I want to update the selected option, I also need to provide the initial list of options, which never changes...
How can I update the selected options without having to provide each time the list of options? Since the method RadioGroup can't be divided, and the hoisting must be at the lowest for reading and highest for writing.

Thanks for the advice guys.

Comment: hello, please add view model implementation

Comment: The viewmodel has an init function that post on the livedata with the list of options and a default selected option. The function onOptionSelected(option: String) also posts on the livedata + do some stuff with that option

Comment: I need to see `onOptionSelected` function and `selected` variable definition

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to have 2 seperate state for each parameters:

```
val options = viewModel.options.observeAsState().value
val selection = viewModel.selection.observeAsState().value
```

and voila :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Radio Group like this:-

```
@Composable
fun displayRadioGroup(){
    var selected by remember { mutableStateOf("Male") }
    Row {
        RadioButton(selected = selected == "Male", onClick = { selected = "Male" })
        Text(
            text = "Male",
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = { selected = "Male" }).padding(start = 4.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(4.dp))
        RadioButton(selected = selected == "Female", onClick = { selected = "Female" })
        Text(
            text = "Female",
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = { selected = "Female" }).padding(start = 4.dp)
        )
    }
}
```